# Can't get jquery ui modal dialog to show input form

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a web page on which is displayed Thai phrases with their English counterparts. When an icon alongside the English text is clicked, a modal dialog is displayed and the English  is obscured. I want the dialog to show an input box where the user will enter the English text. On closing the dialog, the English is made visible again. Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var englishTextId;
  var t2e_dlog =  jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      position: "center",
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,
      dialogClass: "t2e_dlog",
      height: 140,
      width: 400,
      create: function() {                                 
          jQuery(this).parents(".ui-dialog")
          .css("border", "solid black 1px")                            
          .css("background", "#FFFFE8")
          .css("border-radius", "3px")            
          .find(".ui-dialog-content")
          .css("font-family", "verdana")
          .css("font-size", "0.65em")
          .css("font-style", "normal")
          .css("color",   "#1901B2")
          .css("padding", "5px 1px")
          .find(".ui-dialog-header")
          .css("display","none");       
      }
  });

  jQuery("span.t2e_icon").on("click", function(evnt) { 
     t2e_dlog.dialog("open");
     evnt.stopPropagation();
     // obscures the selected phrase
     var elementId = evnt.target.id;
     englishTextId = ("span#t1ee" + elementId.substring(7));
     // obscures text in the page associated with the dialog box
     jQuery(englishTextId).css({"border-radius" : "3px","background" : "blue", "color" : "blue"});
   });  

    jQuery(function() {
       // removes the dialog box title bar
      jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog();
      jQuery("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").hide();
      jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');
      // placemarker html
      var input = "<p>Please enter  the English phrase here:</p><p>hello</p>"; 
      jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").append(input); 
  }); 
    jQuery(function() {    
      jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").dialog({
       // unobscures text   
       beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {
         jQuery(englishTextId).css({"border-radius" : "3px","background" : "", "color" : ""});
       }
     });   
 });   
});
```

The above code works with the indicated html placemarker,

```
<p>Please enter the English phrase here:</p>
```

But if this is replaced with an html form, like

```
<form id="t2eForm" action="#"><input type="text" id="t2e_w" name="t2eWrite"></form>
```

the dialog is not displayed. I've looked around online but can't see anything really relevant. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/AvaY6/

Comment: Yeah, I found the error, single quote double quote confusion, changing the outermost set of quotes from double to single in the form html solved the problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ok I'll add the comment as answer ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your input variable have a `'` and `"` mixup, try to fix it like:

```
var input = '<form id="t2eForm" action="#"><input type="text" id="t2e_w" name="t2eWrite"></form>';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/AvaY6/